# Why doesn't debugger stop in a drupal hook_menu function?

Tags: debugging, netbeans, drupal-7, hook

I'm trying to verify that a hook_menu function is being executed but the debugger (netbeans) doesn't stop at a breakpoint set at the function. It will stop at callback set in the module file but not the hook_menu function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal documentation writes:

> This hook enables modules to register paths in order to define how URL
>   requests are handled. Paths may be registered for URL handling only,
>   or they can register a link to be placed in a menu (usually the
>   Navigation menu). A path and its associated information is commonly
>   called a "menu router item". **This hook is rarely called (for example,
>   when modules are enabled), and its results are cached in the database**.

You can use the `devel` module which provides some development links where you are able to `rebuild menu` which will call your `hook_menu` each time.